In the supply demand model $Q_s=a_0+a_1P+u$ and $Q_d=b_0+b_1P+b_2Y+v$, is it true that $a_0,a_1$ are identified while $b_0,b_1,b_2$ are not?
In the supply demand model $Q_s=a_0+a_1P+u$ and $Q_d=b_0+b_1P+b_2Y+v$ and $Q_s=Q_d$, where $P$ is price, $Y$ is income, $u,v$ are the unobserved error terms.  what are the identified parameters and non-identified parameters in the model? is it true that $a_0,a_1$ are identified while $b_0,b_1,b_2$ are not? It would be great if you could illustrate with some rigor (or prove it) possibly under some additional reasonable assumptions that you would like to impose. Thanks in advance!
